# Schedule task for Node.js web application

Tags: node.js, web, scheduled-tasks, real-time, johnny-five

I have made a web real time application that connected to Node.js server through a websocket. In my website I can turn on/off an LED connected to Arduino Uno.

What I want to do is, I want my website have capability to turn on/off led at certain date and time dynamically. What I mean 'dynamically' is I can add new or remove current schedule task.

I have been trying using node-schedule, cron, but it's just a static schedule task. I can't change or add new task.

Answer (score 0):

Use a db / file. You can store the dates in a json and then edit it as per your convenience. Use node-cron to create events of what you wanna do from the data. Create function that removes entry from json when you want to and it also remove it from the upcoming tasks by `task.destroy()` method of node-cron.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it. Btw, I have a MySQL database in my website. Can I use that instead of json?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can.

Comment: can you give me an example for "node-cron to create event"?

Comment: Its right there on the about page of the module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kdichev/Green-Systems/blob/development/PumpController.js

check what I have done with my pump. on line 19 I have an array of times that will run the pump according to the entries given.